# Assistance with Proving if sets are convex or not.

Tags: proof-writing, convex-analysis

I'm trying to see if the following sets are convex for all $x$.  I proved $S_1$, but having trouble with $S_2$ and $S_3$.

$S_1 = \{x \in R^n : \lVert Ax \rVert \leq 1\} $
$S_2= \{x \in R^n : \lVert Ax \rVert \geq 1\} $
$S_3= \{x \in R^{2n} : \sum_{k=1}^{n} x^2_k \leq \sum_{k=n+1}^{2n} x^2_k \} $

$S_1$:

\begin{equation} \label{eq1}
\begin{split}
\lVert A(\alpha x + (1 - \alpha)y)\rVert & = \lVert \alpha A x + (1 - \alpha)Ay\rVert \\
 & \leq  \alpha\lVert A x \rVert +(1 - \alpha)\lVert  Ay\rVert \\
& = \alpha(1) + (1-\alpha)(1) = 1
\end{split}
\end{equation}
Therefore $S_{1}$ is convex because norms cannot be negative and therefore it must be equal to 1.

For $S_2$, intuitively I can see that it is concave. But how can I show this? I would prefer to see a proof rather than a counterexample.

For $S_3$, I don't even know how to start.

Thanks!

Comment: It may be obvious, but which norm are we considering? A specific one or any norm?

Comment: Sorry this the the L2 (euclidian norm).

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $S_2$ is non-empty, and if $x \in S_2$, then we also have $-x \in S_2$, check that $0 \notin S_2$ and you can make a conclusion.

For $S_3$, let's first consider the special case for $n=1$, then we have $(1,1) \in S_3$ and $(1,-1)\in S_3$, check that their midpoint $(1,0) \notin S_3$. Use this idea to generalize to arbitrary $n$.